# Map markers are disappearing after a certain amount of toggle clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Very strange problem. I have items on a list. They toggle on click to expanded and collapse. When expanded, the items that show under it also appear as markers on a google map that I have on the page. In my test, I have one item on the list. As I click, the associated items underneath it show and their markers show on the map, or hide depending upon toggle state.

Consistently, after exactly 11 clicks of this item showing and hiding stuff on the map, one of the markers that is supposed to show no longer shows. I have no idea why it's exactly 11 clicks every time. Even stranger, if I drag or zoom on the map, the missing marker shows up right away. Because of that clue, I know where the problem is and I disabled it for now and the problem went away. Here's the associated code

```
function setNewMarkers() {
    //clearOldMarkers();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
        bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    /*if (dragged == false && dblclick == false) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        if (markers.length == 1) {
            map.setZoom(13);
        }
    }*/
```

}

notice the commented out section at the bottom. That was the problem and it went away after comment out. I was trying to prevent the map from zooming in too far if there is only one marker (home base marker) and all list items are collapsed. **So I have to call fitBounds, but something is wrong with the way I am adjusting the zoom afterwards if there is only one marker**, even though it works for 10 clicks.

So I am missing a subtlety and I think there is probably a better way to approach this that I am not aware of. Thx.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't call fitBounds if there is only one marker.

Comment: That's a thought. Maybe I should instead take the one leftover marker's lat lng and make the map center to be that and THEN make the zoom 13. Let me see what others say as well. thx.

Comment: That's a good idea and it appears to work fine. If you could add an answer here and include this in your recommendation, I can mark it. map.panTo(markers[0].getPosition()); instead of map.fitBounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling fitBounds twice when you have a single marker.  Instead, you know what the center is (the one existing marker) and the zoom you want, just use those.

```
function setNewMarkers() {
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  if (dragged == false && dblclick == false) {
    if (markers.length == 1) {
        map.panTo(markers[0].getPosition());
        map.setZoom(13);
    }
  }
}
```